# PHPExcel does not take variable into cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to get variables into a `PHPExcel` file.

When I open the page without variables it shows me an excellent Excel document. Once I add the variables into the cells, the excel sheet turns white and returns nothing. I know it is possible to call variables into `ExcelSheets`, I have no clue why it is not working.

**Code:**

```
// Add Data in your file
            foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
            $timestamp = substr($value['timestamp'], 6, 10);
            $timestamp = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp);     

 //Table
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'Beller ')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'Beller nummer')
            ->setCellValue('F2', 'Datum')
            ->setCellValue('H2', 'ontvanger naam')
            ->setCellValue('J2', 'ontvanger nummer')
            ->setCellValue('L2', 'Billing seconds')
            ->setCellValue('N2', 'Direction')
// array 

            ->setCellValue('B3', $value ['caller_id_name'])
            ->setCellValue('D3', $value ['caller_id_number'])
            ->setCellValue('F3', $timestamp)
            ->setCellValue('H3', $value ['callee_id_name'])
            ->setCellValue('J3', $value ['callee_id_number'])
            ->setCellValue('L3', $value ['billing_seconds'])
            ->setCellValue('N3', $value ['direction']);         

                }
```

To clarify the situation: when I use the variables it returns an empty excel sheet (white screen).

When I try it without variables it returns me exactly what I want, but I want that this also work with my variable.

```
// Add Data in your file
            //Werkt niet            foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
            //Werkt niet            $timestamp = substr($value['timestamp'], 6, 10);
            //werkt niet            $timestamp = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp);     

 //Table
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'Beller ')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'Beller nummer')
            ->setCellValue('F2', 'Datum')
            ->setCellValue('H2', 'ontvanger naam')
            ->setCellValue('J2', 'ontvanger nummer')
            ->setCellValue('L2', 'Billing seconds')
            ->setCellValue('N2', 'Direction')
// array 

            ->setCellValue('B3', 'hi')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'hi')
            ->setCellValue('F3', 'hi')
            ->setCellValue('H3', 'hi')
            ->setCellValue('J3', 'ontvanger nummer')
            ->setCellValue('L3', 'Billing seconds')
            ->setCellValue('N3', 'Direction');          

            //Werkt niet            }
```

Comment: First thing to do is some basic debugging and find out if `$value` really does contain the array that you believe it contains, because PHPExcel neither knows nor cares whether the value argument of a `setCellValue()` is a variable or a hard-coded string, what matters is the actual value.... if that's an empty string or a null value, then that's what it will store in the cell

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue. (I tried to put data from MySQL table into Excell sheet, but it could not worked) so I found that the setCellValue accepts only UTF-8 strings. And Tthat is solved my problem. So I suggest you to use the **utf8_encode** function like:

```
->setCellValue('B3', utf8_encode( $value ['caller_id_name'] ) )
```

P.